Apparent Contradiction About the Work Done on a Dielectric Slab in a Capacitor
Consider a dielectric slab positioned between the plates of a capacitor.
When the capacitor is charged, the work done on the dielectric is $\delta W= E d\mu$ (I derived this formula below).
Can you explain the interpretation of this work? I don't understand it because it seems to contradict the following simple observation: for an electric dipole in an electric field, the potential energy is $U=- E \cdot \mu $, which leads to $dU=\delta W=-E d\mu$.
Derivation of $\delta W=E d \mu$
Let $A$ represent the area parallel to the plates, $l$ the slab's thickness, and $delta V = El$ the potential difference applied across the capacitor.
The work required to transfer a charge $\delta Q$ to the plates is given by $\delta W = El \delta Q$.
We can write the charge as $Q = DA$, where $D = \epsilon_0 E + P$.
The electric dipole moment of the dielectric is $\mu = AlP$.
Substituting, we can write $dQ=A(\epsilon_0 dE + \frac{d\mu}{Al}) \rightarrow \delta W=Al\epsilon_0 E dE + E d\mu $
So, the work due to the polarization is $E=E d \mu$.
